# How to format DVD-RAM?

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-10.04, udf

I have few DVD-RAM disks and when using udftools, specifically

```
sudo mkudffs --media-type=dvdram /dev/sr0
```

where /dev/sr0 is my DVD-RAM drive, I get `trying to change type of multiple extents` and nothing happens.

What should I do?

**EDIT**

After trying with dvd+tools, here's what I got:

```
#dvd+rw-format /dev/dvd -format=full -ssa=default
* BD/DVD±RW/-RAM format utility by <appro@fy.chalmers.se>, version 7.1.
* 4.6GB DVD-RAM media detected.
* formatting 54.8|
```

And same error as before from mkudffs.

Answer (score 1):

One day, I got 20 new (unused ... but old) DVD-RAM disks. When I tried to use them with Linux, it didn't work with K3b or other excellent programs.
So, I used them with a Windows 7 and later with Win Windows or Win Windows.

Once upon a time, I found `mkfs.udf` == m`kudffs`, very nice, but it was only for simulate the job, even without the `-n` option.

Later, I finally discovered `dvd+rw-format`.

Then I remembered that very, very old time, when we had the first hard disk of 10MB. That is true! With those disk (MFM ones I think) you had to make a low level format to prepare the surface, and a high level format to put on it the file system.

It seems that the problem with DVD-RAM disks should be similar, and K3b (and others), without the 1st step, doesn't see any disk because the surface is too "smooth"!

Finally, I could do the job with, using the two programs, as said above, with the good options.

Here is the whole stuff:

1. First, you make the low level format:

   ```
   $ dvd+rw-format -force=full /dev/sr0
   BD/DVD±RW/-RAM format utility by <appro@fy.chalmers.se>, version 7.1.
   4.6GB DVD-RAM media detected.
   formatting 100.0|
   ```

   - It begins with the last line "* formatting 0.0/" and it takes about 40 minutes to reach "* formatting 100.0" (%); so be patient!
   - `-force=full` is used option to get the disk formatted to the end.
2. Then, it is mandatory to set up the UDF file system:

   ```
   $ mkudffs --utf8 -m dvdram -l 11_UDF_20221125 /dev/sr0
   filename=/dev/sr0

   label=11_UDF_20221125
   uuid=63808097e8737748
   blocksize=2048
   blocks=2236703
   udfrev=2.01
   start=0, blocks=16, type=RESERVED 
   start=16, blocks=4, type=VRS 
   start=20, blocks=76, type=USPACE 
   start=96, blocks=16, type=MVDS 
   start=112, blocks=16, type=USPACE 
   start=128, blocks=4, type=LVID 
   start=132, blocks=124, type=USPACE 
   start=256, blocks=1, type=ANCHOR 
   start=257, blocks=2236189, type=PSPACE 
   start=2236446, blocks=1, type=ANCHOR 
   start=2236447, blocks=65, type=USPACE 
   start=2236512, blocks=16, type=RVDS 
   start=2236528, blocks=174, type=USPACE 
   start=2236702, blocks=1, type=ANCHOR
   ```

   - `--utf8` option must be the first one on the line to be effective;
   - `-m dvdram` option to get the correct dimention parameters for a dvd-ram;
   - `-l 11_UDF_20221125` will give the label (for me 11th disk, UDF, and created on 25 nov. 2022).
3. Finaly, mount the file system (usually open and close the tray is enough)**

   ```
   $ sudo mount -t auto /dev/sr0 sr0_mount_point
   ```

   - `/dev/sr0` for me, change for your 'local' drive.
4. All that job done you can also verify it :**

   ```
   $ mount -l | grep /dev/sr0**

   /dev/sr0 on sr0_mount_point type udf (rw,relatime,utf8) 11_UDF_20221125]
   ```

   - `-l` option for mount, to see the mount points with their label, and
   - `| grep /dev/sr0`, to get the only line of my first DVD-CD-BD drive.

So, on the DVD-RAM disk there is now a UDF file system, UTF8 caracters encoded utf8, and labeled, as Iwanted, 11_UDF_20221125!

The same way, you can do make UDF file system on with CD-RW, DVD-RW or DVD+RW with their specific -m cdrw, -m dvdrw for `mkfs.udf` == `mkudffs`.

If you want an other file system on your disk, you can use the other `mkfs.xxxx` programs for the 2nd step.

Have a lot of fun, my friends!

Answer (score 0):

How to format a DVD with UDF

```
mkudffs /dev/dvd
```

If that fails with a `trying to change type of multiple extents` error, then it's likely that you've got a virgin disk. If you have the dvd+rw-tools package, you can re-format it with the following command:

```
dvd+rw-format /dev/dvd
```

Then run the mkudffs command again.

<sup><sub>**[Source of above info](http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/how-to-format-a-dvd-with-udf.html)**</sub></sup>

Comment: /dev/dvd is a link to /dev/sr0 and it too fails. I'll try with dvd+rw-format.

Comment: Format just finished and I'm still getting same error.

Comment: As a  sidenote, I just tried mkudffs on a known working CD-RW and I got same error.

Comment: After several dvd+rw-format /dev/dvd I noticed that it exits before 100%. Every time it completes a few percent more and I'm at 97.9% now.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Seems your problem lies somewhere else. I'll convert this answer to community wiki in case it helps someone else.